# How I can pass command line arguments (encrypted)- Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

I have Travis build where I need to run command 
"terraform plan -var subscription_key=23456"

i do not want to display my "subscription_key" while the travis execute the build, is there any workaround through which I can encrypt the values and provide it in Travis check?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define [encrypted env variable](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypting-environment-variables) e.g. `MY_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY` and change your script to: `terraform plan -var subscription_key=$MY_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY`

You can also encrypt whole script line using `travis encrypt "terraform plan -var subscription_key=23456" --add script`

This will add something like:

```
 script:
    - secure: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

to your `.travis.yml`.

Of course you have to have travis command line client [installed](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#installation).